# Reorganizing and sorting lines from a read file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm still rather new to python, and am currently stuck on a problem.
I'm trying to read a simple .txt file and print the lines in a new order relating the the numbers in each line. (lowest to highest)

The .txt is currently:

> ```
> House 7
> Office 2
> Skyscraper 5
> Shack 9
> Condo 8
> ```

What I need my print to look like:

> ```
> 2 Office
> 5 Skyscraper
> 7 House
> 8 Condo
> 9 Shack
> ```

My code so far is:

```
inFile = open("dogs.txt", "r")

for line in inFile:
   strLine = line.split()
   strLine = (strLine[1] + " " + strLine[0])

   print(strLine)
```

I've been able to get the numbers on the left side, but am having issues sorting the lines now. I've tried to implement ".sort()" and "sorted" in multiple ways, but I don't think I understand enough about them to properly make them work. I've seen that maybe I should use "append()", but again, I'm not familiar enough with that method to be able to use the correct syntax.

Comment: Search on line for "Python sort tutorial".  There are plenty of examples.  Also, we can't fix code you haven't posted: there is no attempt to sort in the example you give.

Comment: The idea would be to first read the whole file line by line into a list and then sort that list and finaly print it out with the format you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort them by using 2nd item in the inner list

```
inFile = open("dogs.txt", "r")
lines = []
for line in inFile:
   strLine = line.strip().split(' ')
   strLine = (strLine[1] + " " + strLine[0])
   lines.append(strLine)
a = '\n'.join(sorted(lines,key= lambda lines:lines[0]))
print(a)
```

Output:

```
2 Office
5 Skyscraper
7 House
8 Condo
9 Shack
```

Also remember to strip the whitespaces, because you are reading a file and at the end of each line you'll have a `\n` character

Answer (score 1):

Sort lines by second item in list after splitting.

```
with open("dogs.txt", "r") as in_file:
    lines = [line.split() for line in in_file]

sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: int(x[1].strip()))

for line in sorted_lines:
    print(" ".join(reversed(line)))
```